# List order (or iteration) malfunction

Tags: c#, list, loops

Hello I am having trouble with an iteration through a *list* of 17 labels:

```
for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count - 1; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(labels[i].Name);
    if (labels[i].Visible == false && labels[i + 1].Visible == true)
    {
        ...
```

Here are the results I get:

First it goes from `label10` to `label17`, and then in descending order from `label9` to `label2`.

Here is how I add the labels to the list:

```
private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is Label)
        {
            labels.Add(c);
            c.Enabled = true;
            if (c.Visible == false)
            {
                c.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to go from `label1` to `label16`, since the loop is just a loop I guess the problem lies in the order in which the labels were added to the list, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: labels[i + 1].Visible might throw an IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: Can you show us your designer code?

Comment: @Serge It won't throw exception since the upper limit of the loop counter is `i < labels.Count - 1`

Comment: @Nikola, you're right about the index yet I'm surprised by that -1. Are you really willing to iterate through all the label BUT the last one?

Comment: @Serge Check the question, the OP said that he specifically wants to iterate from label1 to label16

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is lexicographic order which is inherently used when you sort by Name of the label, what you want is to sort by numbers after the term `label`. In that case, first sort the labels list and then run the for statement over it, check the code:

```
var lst = labels.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Name.Substring("label".Length))).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count - 1; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(lst[i].Name);
    ...
```

But have in mind that this code is simple and presumes that label Name property always starts with "label" string. If that can change you must handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to sort the labels according to their names?

```
labels.Sort((x, y) => { return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name); });
```

but what are the difference between:

1. Show "Label 1" first, then "Label 2", and
2. Show "Label 2" first, then "Label 1"?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `designer.cs` file to see in which order the labels are added to the Form

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have Labels id as Label1,Label2..........,Label16
in order to get the labels serially you have to write the following code

```
labels = labels.ConvertAll<Control>(GetIdFromLabel);
labels.Sort((x, y) => { return x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id); });

public Control GetIdFromLabel(Control c)
    {
        c.Id = c.Name.Replace("Label", "") == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(c.Name.Replace("Label", ""));
        return c;
    }
```

add this class in your code also

```
public class Control
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labels.Clear();
        Control[] matches;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            matches = this.Controls.Find("label" + i.ToString(), true);
            if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Label)
            {
                Label lbl = (Label)matches[0];
                labels.Add(lbl);
                lbl.Enabled = true;
                if (lbl.Visible == false)
                {
                    lbl.Visible = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```